# cleaning CSV String/varchar in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got some quirks in a varchar field that is designated to be used as a CSV (comma separated values) that I'd like to clean up.

for example extra comma: `val1, ,val2, val3` or a trailing comma `val1, val2,`

how do I craft a SQL that replaces `, ,` with `,` and removes the last character if it is a `,` ?

Comment: before or after importing the file to your database?

Comment: after, (it's not really a file, just values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT REPLACE(columnName, ', ,', ', ')
FROM   TableName
```

*this may not work always especially when you have multiple spaces between comma.*

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regexp_replace` function if you use oracle db

```
select  REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('val1, ,val2, val3,', ',\s,', ','),'[,]$','')
from dual
```

in MySql you can write you own function like in [Rasika's Blog](http://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

ended up using a like selector and replace

```
-- clean tags, remove empty tags
Update [myTable]
set [taglist] = REPLACE([taglist], ', ,', ', ')
  WHERE [taglist] like '%, ,%' -- not really needed, I know

  -- remove last comma
Update [myTable]
set [taglist] = SUBSTRING([taglist], 0, LEN([taglist]))
  WHERE [taglist] like '%,'
```